# "that which" vs. "what"

Tags: differences, which-that, that

What's the difference between "that which" and "what"?

Which of the following sentences is correct, and how (if at all) do they differ?

> We only want to free technology from *that which* makes it inhuman.
>   We only want to free technology from *what* makes it inhuman.

<sup>(example from [*Return to Order*](http://www.returntoorder.org/the-book/) ch. 10, penultimate ¶)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference in actual meaning.

"that which" is more formal, appropriate in traditional or literary writing.

"what" is good for everyday use, especially in speech.

Answer (score -2):

I think I can be of a little help to you.

When you have a range of options to choose from, you use which. When you choose from unlimited available options you use what.

I am not sure about it thought.

I remember my teacher say "No two sentences are the same in meaning.'

Hope that helped.